# SAML - Get attributes from client side or Java ee REST api

Tags: javascript, java, rest, saml

I need to get attributes of the account from SAML identity provider. Is there any way to do it from client-side (javascript, browser) or using java ee REST API(JAX-RS)?

I have found many tutorials about using SAML but they always describe a process of authorization application(always use server-side and jsp/jsf). I don't need it. I just want to read attributes of account.

My identity provider also support OpenID Connect and OpenId 2.0

Could you help me? I tried to search for it but maybe I use the wrong keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of getting the attributes:

- Via a protocol e.g. SAML or OIDC. To do this you have to follow the rules of the protocol i.e. authenticate first
- Go direct to the identity store e.g. if the store is AD, you can use the LDAP protocol. You need to connect to the LDAP store first.